# Split dataset of images into train test split for CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I'm training a CNN on kaggle and my data consists of two things: 1 csv file of labels and 1 folder of images. How can I split the data on kaggle into train test split? Thanks.

[image]

Here is one example image:

[image]

and the associated label(from the csv):

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide the code you are using to load and work with the data? There are many ways to accomplish this, and a good answer will depend on the specifics of your situation.

Comment: Yes. Here is my labels: https://www.kaggle.com/richardcao1/phonemes and here is my pictures: https://www.kaggle.com/richardcao1/phoneme-images. The images and phonemes correspond to each other

Comment: Please paste an example each of image and label in the question itself (as per stackoverflow guidelines)

Comment: I have added an example

Comment: The different directory is not the main problem. Your dataset contains some problems, the label doesn't contain the image file id. You need to annotate it first properly.

Comment: So I need to have the phoneme label contain the image path?

Comment: Since the data isn't much big, you can just read all annotations and image and group them. After, simply apply `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function below creates train, test, and validation generators are given:
source dir - full path to the directory containing all the images
cvs_path - path to CSV file that has a column (`x_col`) containing a string of the filename and a column (`y_col`) that contains the string of the class associated filename

note: source_dir/filename results in a path to the file in the source_dir
This function automatically determines the batch_size for the generator and steps to us in `model.fit` so that you go through the train, test, or validation images exactly once per epoch. `max_batch_size` specifies the largest batch size you allow based on memory constraints train_split - float between 0 and 1 specifying the percentage of images used for training test_split - float between 0 and 1 specifying the percentage of images used for training note the validation_split is calculated internally as 1 - train_split - test_split
target_size= tuple(height, width) input images are adjust to
scale - float- pixels are rescaled to pixels* scale ( typically 1/255)
class_mode - see keras flow_from_dataframe for details typically use 'categorical'

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
def train_test_valid_split(source_dir, cvs_path,max_batch_size, train_split, test_split, x_col, y_col, class_mode, target_size, scale):
    data=pd.read_csv(cvs_path).copy()
    te_split=test_split/(1-train_split)    
    train_df=data.sample(n=None, frac=train_split, replace=False, weights=None, random_state=123, axis=0)
    tr_batch_size= max_batch_size
    tr_steps=int(len(train_df.index)//tr_batch_size)     
    dummy_df=data.drop(train_df.index, axis=0, inplace=False)     
    test_df=dummy_df.sample(n=None, frac=te_split, replace=False, weights=None, random_state=123, axis=0)
    te_batch_size, te_steps=get_bs(len(test_df.index),max_batch_size )    
    valid_df=dummy_df.drop(test_df.index, axis=0)
    v_batch_size,v_steps=get_bs(len(valid_df.index), max_batch_size)
    gen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=scale)
    train_gen=gen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=train_df, directory=source_dir,batch_size=tr_batch_size, x_col=x_col, y_col=y_col,
                                      target_size=target_size, class_mode=class_mode,seed=123,  validate_filenames=False)    
    test_gen=gen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=test_df, directory=source_dir, batch_size=te_batch_size, x_col=x_col, y_col=y_col,
                                     target_size=target_size, class_mode=class_mode,  shuffle=False,validate_filenames=False)
    valid_gen=gen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=valid_df, directory=source_dir,batch_size=v_batch_size, x_col=x_col, y_col=y_col, 
                                      target_size=target_size, class_mode=class_mode, shuffle=False,validate_filenames=False)    
    return train_gen, tr_steps, test_gen, te_steps, valid_gen , v_steps

def get_bs(length, b_max):
    batch_size=sorted([int(length/n) for n in range(1,length+1) if length % n ==0 and length/n<=b_max],reverse=True)[0]
    steps=int(length//batch_size)
    return batch_size, steps
```

the CSV file is of the form

```
    file_id     class_id
0   00000.jpg   AFRICAN CROWNED CRANE
1   00001.jpg   AFRICAN CROWNED CRANE
2   00002.jpg   AFRICAN CROWNED CRANE
3   00003.jpg   AFRICAN CROWNED CRANE
4   00004.jpg   AFRICAN CROWNED CRANE
5   00005.jpg   AFRICAN CROWNED CRANE
6   00006.jpg   AFRICAN CROWNED CRANE
7   00007..jpg  AFRICAN CROWNED CRANE
8   00008..jpg  AFRICAN CROWNED CRANE
```

Below is an example of the use

```
source_dir=r'c:\temp\birds\consolidated_images'
cvs_path=r'c:\temp\birds\birds.csv'
train_split=.8
test_split=.1
x_col='file_id'
y_col='class_id'
target_size=(224,224)
scale=1/127.5-1
max_batch_size=32
class_mode='categorical'
train_gen, train_steps, test_gen, test_steps, valid_gen, valid_steps=train_test_valid_split(source_dir,
                cvs_path, max_batch_size, train_split, test_split, x_col, y_col, class_mode, target_size, scale)
print ('train steps: ', train_steps, '  test steps: ', test_steps, '  valid steps: ', valid_steps)
```

results from execution are

```
Found 30172 non-validated image filenames belonging to 250 classes.
Found 3772 non-validated image filenames belonging to 250 classes.
Found 3771 non-validated image filenames belonging to 250 classes.
train steps:  942   test steps:  164   valid steps:  419
```

now use these generators

```
epochs= 20 # set to what you want
history=model.fit(x=train_gen, epochs=epochs,steps_per_epoch=train_steps,   
            validation_data=valid_gen, validation_steps=valid_steps,
            shuffle=False,  verbose=1)
```

after training

```
accuracy=model.evaluate(test_gen, steps=test_steps)[1]*100
print ('Model accuracy on test set is', accuracy)
```

or to do predictions

```
predictions=model.predict(test_gen, steps=test_steps, verbose=1)
```

Comment: What does the function "get_bs_steps" do?

Comment: It calculates the batch_size and steps per epoch given the number of samples. such that batch_size times steps equals number of samples. Using these values in model.fit or model,predict ensures you go through all samples exactly once per epoch

Comment: I get an error "TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object"

Comment: can you specify more about where the error occurs?

Comment: think I found the error - will repost answer shortly

Comment: posted correct code- copied the wrong code previously

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to work. The training data is in the form of "DataFrameIterator", how should I use it to train my model? Will "history = model.fit(train_gen,train_steps, epochs = 30, batch_size = 256, validation_data = (valid_gen, valid_steps), shuffle = True)" work? I think I also need to reshape the data to 4th dimensions but the .reshape function does not seem to work.

Comment: history=model.fit(x=train_gen,  epochs=20, steps_per_epoch=train_steps,verbose=1,
                       validation_data=valid_gen, validation_steps=valid_steps,
                      shuffle=False)

Comment: see modified answer to respond to you question

Comment: Thank you very much. For some reason, I am unable to compile my model. My model is here:
`
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(filters= 64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation ='relu',strides = (2,2) padding = 'valid', input_shape= (8113, 64,64, 1)))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(39)) 

model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229067/discussion-between-allen-ye-and-gerry-p).

Answer (score -2):

```
import splitfolders

# Define paths
input_folder = 'path/to/dataset/all_images'
output_folder = 'path/to/output/folder'

# Split the dataset into train, validation, and test sets
splitfolders.ratio(input_folder, output=output_folder, seed=42, ratio=(0.7, 0.15, 0.15))
```

Comment: Not quite sure how this answers the question (a question already answered, with an accepted answer, over 2 years ago). Plus it's just some code and no explanation.